# DIY mikveh Idea

Tags: mikvah-ritual-bath

So, I'm starting to consider how to build a keli mikvah at home, and plastic stock tanks look like an easy solution, except they are kelim themselves.

My question - before I go to my LOR, I'm just trying to get a sense check here - is, if I were to drill a big hole in the bottom, or even cut off the bottom and re-attach as I build, would that remediate the problem enough?

Also,

also, I understand that that gutters don't count for collection, so I'd need to build a separate collection pan on the roof?

Comment: See YD 201:7 and :40

Comment: People did this during Covid. There was even a company that offered to do it for you

Comment: See: https://www.homemikveh.org/intro.html

Comment: IRC anything bigger than 40 Seah is not considered a Keli - but this is a LOR issue, par excellence.